# powershell- recursive call to rename file names in bulk

Tags: powershell, recursion

I am trying renaming the files recursively. 
My sample file name is:

> 2011.02.21 Work Plan - Greg Graham_v1.0__977a6c84-340a-442f-997e-aea94308b382.pdf

I want to delete the string `__977a6c84-340a-442f-997e-aea94308b382` which starts with two underscore + 36 characters of identifier.

So result filename will be :

> 2011.02.21 Work Plan - Greg Graham_v1.0.pdf

All the files are in the mentioned folders or subfolders.
I am using following PowerShell :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Recover\test  -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName{$_.name -replace{$_.name.SubString({$_name.IndexOf("__")},38)},""}
```

When I was using `-WhatIf` then it shows all the files. But if I use without `-WhatIf` . It doesn't delete anything.
With`-WhatIf` it shows both target and destination filenames same.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Possibly the original code fails because of braces, rather than parens in the `rename-item` expression...

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off with a regex match. Something like:

```
GCI $path -recurse | Where{$_.BaseName -match "(.+?)__.{36}$"} | ForEach{Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($Matches[1])$($_.extension)"}
```

That will capture the beginning of the file's name (assuming the file name without extension ends in two underscores followed by 36 characters), and then rename the file based on that capture, and the file's original extension.